# Command not found

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-ndk

I am using ubuntu and trying to build a project and I am using the following code:

```
  cd <project-directory>/tess-two
   ndk-build
  android update project --path .
  ant release
```

When I type ndk-build it returns command not found. It returns command not found.I extracted the ndk bin file and made it a folder. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `ndk-build` directory to `PATH`. For example: if your ndk is in directory `/opt/android-ndk-r10d`, run this command first

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/android-ndk-r10d
```

You'd better add the command to ~/.bashrc if you don't want to run this command later.